# How to inherit partial class for stored procedure call

Tags: c#-4.0, inheritance

I have this class as parent class:

```
public partial class GetStuffResult
{

    private int _Id;

    private string _Name;

    public GetStuffResult()
    {
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Id", DbType="INT NOT NULL")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this._Id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Name != value))
            {
                this._Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is base class which has same methods with exception of an extra method:

```
public partial class GetStuffResult1
{
    private int _Score;

    private int _Id;

    private string _Name;

    public GetStuffResult1()
    {
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Score", DbType="INT NOT NULL")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Score;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Score != value))
            {
                this._Score = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Id", DbType="INT NOT NULL")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this._Id = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Column(Storage="_Name", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Name;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Name != value))
            {
                this._Name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have done inheritance before but i am totally confused how it will work in this scenario? How can i inherit GetStuffResult so that i can use its 2 methods and dont have to copy paste same code twice in GetStuffResult1. 
Will appreciate if someone can give example with code as i am new to .net 3.5 and still trying to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I correctly understood your question. *(Your current code for `GetStuffResult1` shouldn't compile as you have define Id property twice.)* If you are looking to inherit from `GetStuffResult` then this would do (See [Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)):

```
public partial class GetStuffResult1 : GetStuffResult
    {
        private int _Score;  

        public GetStuffResult1()
        {
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Score", DbType = "INT NOT NULL")]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Score;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Score != value))
                {
                    this._Score = value;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Notice that I have removed `_Id` and `_Name` from the child class. This however will give you warning that:

> GetStuffResult1.Id' hides inherited member
>   'ThreadConsoleApp.GetStuffResult.Id'. Use the new keyword if hiding
>   was intended.

The second thing I am thinking about your question if you are confused about using partial classes and you may need a single class in multiple source file. In that case you may use [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) keyword. If that is the case and you don't need inheritance then you need to use a single name for the class. e.g. `GetStuffResult`. In that particular case your `GetStuffResult1` will become:

```
public partial class GetStuffResult
    {
        private int _Score;  

        public GetStuffResult1()
        {
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_Score", DbType = "INT NOT NULL")]
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Score;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Score != value))
                {
                    this._Score = value;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

This will be similar to having a single class with all the combined properties.

Edit:

To access the base class properties in the child class, you may use base keyword.

```
    base.Id = 0;
    base.Name = "SomeName";
```

To access the base class properties from the object of `GetStuffResult1`, see the following example.

```
    GetStuffResult1 gsr1 = new GetStuffResult1();
    gsr1.Id = 0;
    gsr1.Name = "SomeName";
```

Here `gsr1.Name` is from the base class, you may use different name for `Id` in either base or child class so that it can be more clearer.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering, I have one more question. So as in the child class we are removing _Id and _Name. How will i call these?

Comment: thanks a lot. I think this helps, i was thinking on same terms but being this a linq query i have never used before it was throwing me off completely. Let me try this. Again thanks a ton!